# GCM 3.0 - can you override Android notifications delivered via notification payload (not data payload)

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform

Can you override an incoming GCM 3.0 Android notification delivered via a notification payload (not data payload)?

For example, to let the user the user disable notifications of a certain type. Obviously this is easily done with the data payload, but I would like to do it via the notification payload if possible.

Also, I think the `icon` json field only sets the `smallIcon` in a notification. Is this any more customizable without using the data payload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is nope.

With a single `topic`, if you want to deliver a push via `notification` payload on iOS, but via `data` payload on Android, you can't!

For example, if you have a `topic` called `"awesome_news"` you should split this into two topics:  `"awesome_news_ios"` and `"awesome_news_android"`